# why does cookies return undefined on server side when logging out after setting them using node js as backend

Tags: node.js, next.js, cookies, setcookie

I'm learning NodeJS and I'm trying to make a login and logout end point, there is no issues with the end point itself as the request returns what it's supposed to return and sets the cookie normally when logging in but the issue is in the logout endpoint as it doesn't define the cookie and logs out undefined.

backend:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const users = {
  users: require("../model/users.json"), //usually gets the data from an outside DB
  setUsers: function (data) {
    this.users = data;
  },
};
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");
const login = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (!username || !password) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ success: false, message: "username and password are required" });
  }
  const userFound = users.users.find((user) => user.username === username);
  if (!userFound) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "user not found" });
  }

  const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userFound.password);
  if (!isPasswordMatch) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, message: " password is invalid" });
  }
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(
    { username: username },
    process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    }
  );
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
    { username },
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "1w",
    }
  );
  const otherUsers = users.users.filter(
    (user) => user.userName != userFound.userName
  );
  const currentUser = { ...userFound, refreshToken };
  users.setUsers([...otherUsers, currentUser]);

  await fsPromises.writeFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../model", "users.json"),
    JSON.stringify(users.users, null, 1),
    "utf-8"
  );

  // Set the cookie after sending the response
  res.cookie("jwt", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours in milliseconds
    sameSite: "None",
    // secure: true, // Only set in production mode when serving over HTTPS
  });

  return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: accessToken });
};
module.exports = { login };
```

logout:

```
 const users = {
  users: require("../model/users.json"), //usually gets the data from an outside DB
  setUsers: function (data) {
    this.users = data;
  },
};
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

const logout = async (req, res) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);
  if (!cookies?.jwt) {
    return res.sendStatus(204); //no content to send back but a successful request
  }
  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;
  //is refreshToken in DB
  const UserFound = users.users.find(
    (user) => user.refreshToken === refreshToken
  );
  if (!UserFound) {
    res.clearCookie("jwt", {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      //secure: true,
    });
    return res
      .status(204)
      .json({ success: true, message: "logged out successfully" });
  }
  const otherUsers = users.users.filter(
    (user) => user.userName != UserFound.userName
  );
  const currentUser = { ...UserFound, refreshToken: "" };
  users.setUsers([...otherUsers, currentUser]);
  await fsPromises.writeFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../model", "users.json"),
    JSON.stringify(users.users, null, 1),
    "utf-8"
  );
  res.clearCookie("jwt", {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    //secure: true,
  }); //in production mode add extra setting called secure:true when modifying the cookie makes it only serve on https websites
  return res
    .status(204)
    .json({ success: true, message: "logged out successfully" }); //no content to send back but a successful request
};
module.exports = { logout };
```

here is a photo of the cookie being set
[image: cookie from the response]

Answer (score 0):

Browser stores http-only cookies and sends it with all requests to the specified domain in it. You can't access these cookies from react or any other frameworks, browser will secure this data from any access.

As you can see it's the main reason why you use it for sensible data such as "refresh token"